# Angular2 - How to make changes on a specific element?

Tags: angular

I have multiple (Add to cart) button on my page, I set the (Add to cart) button to change on (click), so the user can add remove items from the cart seamlessly. The issue is that if the user clicks on one of the buttons all of them changes! Simply because the code does not recognize at which button the user clicked. In the normal scenario, the button that should change is the only one the user clicked-in!
But unfortunately, I don't know how to do it in Angular2.
Thanks for your help!

JS:

```
     addToCart(){
     if (this.amount == 0) {
        this.isCartEmpty = true;
     } else if  (this.amount > 0) {
         this.isCartEmpty = false;
     }   
     }

   addItem() {
    this.amount++;
  }
   removeItem() {
    this.amount--;
  }
```

HTML:

```
    <div *ngIf="isCartEmpty" (click)="addToCart()">ADD TO CART</div>
    <div *ngIf="!isCartEmpty" (click)="addToCart()"><div>

    <div>Element 1</div>
    <div (click)="removeItem()">-</div> 
    <div>{{amount}}</div> 
    <div (click)="addItem()">+</div>
    </div>

    <div>
    <div>Element 2</div>
    <div (click)="removeItem()">-</div> 
    <div>{{amount}}</div> 
    <div (click)="addItem()">+</div>
    </div>

    <div>
    <div>Element 3</div>
    <div (click)="removeItem()">-</div> 
    <div>{{amount}}</div> 
    <div (click)="addItem()">+</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi, I can't find any (Add to cart) button or piece of code that change the buttons. Do you mind providing a complete example?

Comment: @ShuheiKagawa, it's already there, even the first line!

Answer (score 1):

You probably should create your cart as a component:

**my-cart.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

// Creating model here for simplicity. Should be in its own file

export class CartItem {
  public constructor(public name, public amount) { }

  public addItem() {
    this.amount++;
  }

  public removeItem() {
    if (this.amount > 0) {this.amount--};
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-cart',
  template:`
  <p>My Cart</p>
  <button (click)='addCartItem()'>Add Cart Item</button>a
  <button (click)='cleanCart()'>Clean Cart</button><br>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of cartItems">
      {{item.name}}, Amount = {{item.amount}}
      <button (click)='item.addItem()'>Add</button>
      <button (click)='item.removeItem()'>Remove</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
  `
})
export class MyCart {
  private cartItems: [CartItem] = [];

  public addCartItem() {
    this.cartItems.push(new CartItem('Cart item', 1))
  }

  public cleanCart() {
    this.cartItems = this.cartItems.filter(
      (current, i, array) => current.amount > 0;
    )
  }
}
```

[Check it out in Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3IcKYCqTDloY9sGqWcSo?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you Carlos, Your solution indeed works; however, in my case I need two components, etc... which translates to a lot of written code, and related headaches, I believe it can be solved in a much more simpler, easier, cleaner way!

Comment: @Folky.H I'd challenge you to prove your assumption here.  In WHAT way EXACTLY is it MORE challenging to use components than anything else you can think of?

Comment: @DavidL it's not challenging, but it can be done in a much more simpler way, that was my point. I am looking for a way to do it in few lines of code, the same result in achievable in JavaScript in much more less lines

Comment: Hi Folky.H! I edited my answer to have an array of items, as opposed to multiple carts in a page. I think I had misunderstood initially. In my opinion, components is the way to go, especially if you're wanting to use Angular2. This can be solved in many other ways but your question is about Angular2.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have 3 different button to increment the same `amount` variable ?

Are each of these supposed to be three different items ?

Assuming you want 3 different items you could do something like:

```
items = ['A', 'B', 'C']

amount = [0, 0, 0]

addItem(index) {
    this.amount[index]++;
}
removeItem(index) {
    this.amount[index]--;
}
```

html:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
    <div (click)="removeItem(i)">-</div> 
    <div>{{amount[i]}}</div> 
    <div (click)="addItem(i)">+</div>
</div>
```

This should give you an idea. You'll need to fix the code a bit.